# Datagrid Row Update problem

Tags: mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF toolkit Datagrid. I have a rowvalidationrule defined on this. to trigger this validation rule, on each cell update i have to hit enter button. but i want to check this on each cell update without hitting Enter button. How can i do this. this is a MVVM app.
Thanks,
Rey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using IDataErrorInfo and UpdateSourceTrigger=propertychanged to trigger cell level validation.